# Firefox opens with different icon on saved session startup than pinned icon. Is this an issue with Firefox or Ubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, icons, ubuntu-studio, taskbar

I have kubuntu (Ubuntu Studio), and I have it auto-save my desktop session. Firefox starts up with my previous windows and tabs, but it opens a separate instance/icon from what's pinned to Task Manager. I need to either quit and reopen with the pinned icon, or unpin the "old" icon and repin the new one. Is it an issue with Firefox or my OS?

Comment: Probably an issue with saving sessions. Gnome Shell eliminated that option because of issues. A more "modern" way of saving your session would be to sleep or hibernate - although the latter frequently also does not work well, and is actually disabled by default on Ubuntu for that reason.

Comment: I frequently use sleep, though it often results in graphical issues with other apps on wake (unrelated to this, I think). The Firefox issue wasn't a problem until I upgraded my OS and Firefox switched to snap, which I see a lot of people complaining about, though nothing related to my issue (and I generally don't have theirs).